# Datepicker Set endDate Attributes based on input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker from this link:
https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

This is my code:

```
<div class='input-group input-daterange' id="datetimepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
   <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
           maxViewMode: 1,
           datesDisabled: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.dis)],
           orientation: "bottom left",
           keyboardNavigation: false,
           clearBtn: true,
           daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
           startDate: '+2d',
           autoclose: true
       });
```

I am using the range datepicker and it generates 2 input fields, 'start' and 'end'. When I select date for the 'start' field, the `endDate` attribute for 'end' field should be set to "`forDate` I pick + 5 days". How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you build 2 separate datepickers for `start` and `end`?

Comment: Yeah i am planning to do that to, the thing is how to edit endDate based on value of another datepicker? Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **[`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)** method and set respective `startDate` and `endDate` accordingly. Consider below setup:

```
$(function() {
    //initialize on both inputs
    $('#start,#end').datepicker({
        maxViewMode: 1,
        orientation: "bottom left",
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        clearBtn: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
        startDate: '+2d',
        autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        var ctrl = $(this);//get the targeted control
        var selected = new Date(e.date); //get the selected date
        if (ctrl.attr('id') == "start") { //if its a start date
            $("#end").datepicker('setStartDate', new Date(selected.setDate(selected.getDate() + 5))) //set end date + 5
        } else {
            $("#start").datepicker('setEndDate', new Date(selected.setDate(selected.getDate() - 5))) //vice versa for end date
        }
    });
});
```

## [`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/u24ehcfp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#start,#end').datepicker({
        maxViewMode: 1,
        orientation: "bottom left",
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        clearBtn: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
        startDate: '+2d',
        autoclose: true
    });

    $('#start').change(function(){
        var date1 = $('#start').datepicker('getDate');
        var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 5 );

        var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
        newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );

        $('#end').datepicker('setDate', newDate );
    });
});
```